# Doctrine query not executing

Tags: doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2, doctrine-query

trying to execute a Doctrine query that is invariably not happening:
The code I have:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::Create()->select('l.lid')->from('lessons l')->where('l.topic =?','Title of topic')

$result = $q->fetchOne() ;
```

The funny thing is, this returns the wrong column, that is not `l.lid` but `l.someOtherColumn`

So not sure where I am goofing up, your comments and critics are much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: can you post the output of `$q->getSqlQuery()` into your question - this will show the actual request as a plain SQL query and give you a better idea of what its selecting

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Create('table_name t ') instead of ->from() ....